Numerical solution of differential equations, e.g. the three-body problem
What forms of differential equations have numerical solutions with errors that go to zero with sufficient computational power? For example, suppose I want to solve a differential equation $E$ for a position vector $r$ at time $t$, where initial conditions $r(t_0)$, $\dot{r}(t_0)$ are given. What classes of differential equations do we know to have a numerical solution in the form of an algorithm $A_E(r(t_0),\dot{r}(t_0),t,c)$ to predict $\hat{r}(t)$, where is it true that
$\forall \epsilon, \exists c \ni \| \hat{r}(t)-r(t) \| < \epsilon$ (eq. 1),
meaning given any desirable error $\epsilon$, I can use sufficient computational cycles $c$ to predict $\hat{r}(t)$ such that $\|\hat{r}(t)-r(t)\| < \epsilon$?
For a specific example, does the three body problem have a numerical solution
$\hat{r}(t)=A_E(c)$ for $r(t)=(r_{1x}(t),r_{1y}(t),r_{1z}(t),r_{2x}(t),r_{2y}(t),r_{2z}(t),r_{3x}(t),r_{3y}(t),r_{3z}(t))^T$
that satisfies (eq. 1)?
And I believe if such a solution does exist for the three body problem, it is computationally intractable for larger $|t-t_0|$, but that's not what I'm asking. (And I also believe certain initial configurations have been solved analytically). What I really what to know is, what differential equations have numerical solutions $A_E(c)$ satisfying (eq. 1), and is the three body problem in this class?

"I can use sufficient computational cycles $c$" is a pretty strong assumption... If you don't bound $c$ then theoretically you could not only get arbitrary accuracy with an appropriate algorithm but solve any exponential time computer science problem you wanted. Another consideration is that there is also a bound on memory, which is relevant for deciding what time step to use, which in turn determines how quickly errors will accumulate.

@Andrew Hey, you answered my last question, cool. What algorithm can we use if computation complexity is not an issue? And, does the algorithm give error bound?

I mean in principle Euler integration would work. Generally the point of more sophisticated methods used in practice like Runge-Kutta is not to guarantee convergence for a small enough timestep (any method should do that) but to get faster convergence and/or to reduce the rate at which errors accumulate. So they are all about $c$ :)

@Andrew OK, I see from your link that Euler integration is an example of what I was asking. Because we can calculate a global truncation error. Of course, and you point out, this will not be useful for many problems. I was mostly interested in the edge case of exact numerical solution, even if for only small $|t-t_0|$. Thank you for giving a specific algorithm, this is what I didn't know.

Any algorithm for the numerical solution of ordinary differential equations provides a discretized approximation of the exact solution and should guarantee that the global error after a finite time $T$ should vanish by refining the discretization. The quality of different algorithms can be measured by the computational cost of achieving a given threshold of accuracy.
In cases like the gravitational N-body problem, the real issue is not directly related to the numerical algorithms but to the strong dependence of the results on the initial conditions (i.e., to the existence of chaotic motions). In such cases, the form of the differential equation plays only an indirect role in the numerical algorithm. We need more accuracy in the numerical algorithms just to better control the fast divergence of the numerical with respect to the exact solution.
There is no universal recipe for the best algorithm in such cases. It is helpful to compare results with good algorithms from different classes based on the specific problem one is dealing with.

For some differential equations (the Kirkhoff-rules ones that
are useful for electronic networks of resistors, capacitors, inductors),
there is a matrix computation that gives exact results.
When that is the case, there are a variety of error sensitivities
possible, because most matrix operations are not neutral in
the information sense; the input (a vector) may have a large
signal-to-noise ratio, but the output may lessen that (lose
information).   Trivially, a square matrix which is not invertible
(has a zero determinant)  could entirely zero out an input vector
component.   That destroys data.  No subsequent operation can
recover the information; such an  operation would be equivalent
to the nonexistent inverse matrix.
There is a class of matrices that do not have this problem,
which are called 'unitary' matrices.   The discrete Fourier transform,
the FFT, is a unitary matrix.   That means that it is an
information-retaining computational step.
Unitary matrices  have all eigenvalues of order unity, and are
invertible (the inverse of a unitary matrix also is unitary).
So, it is well-understood that there are useful calculation steps
that degrade data; if your equations are correct, and
apply to signal+noise inputs, the absolutely correct
calculations do NOT always give the best results, and
adding computational resources does not ensure final-result
optimal accuracy.
